# How could I make a player stick to walls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3d platformer/puzzle game, the main idea/selling point is that the player can transform into a ball, and can climb onto walls, sort of like flipping gravity. The player can only move on certain walls if they have the specific layer* I'm kinda new to Unity so I would appreciate some help.

I would assume to pull something like this I would need to disable the players rigidbody gravity if they're in the ball form? The rest is all blank to me...

(*tbh I'm not exactly 100% sure what layers are but they're used in these kind of situations right?)

Diagram:
[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches, but definitelly u should do smth with gravity. For example u can set rigidbody as kinematic on entering trigger in ball mode, and set kinematic to false OnTriggerExit or if form returned to humanoid.
Or if u want to reverse gravity towards wall, just rotate whole world 90 degrees

Comment: Thanks, but if I rotate the entire world (assuming I figure out how to) wouldn't other rigidbodies on the scene fall off the world? I also do want physics while on a wall.